# Undefined index in Laravel excel maatwebsite

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I'm so confused about this error because I don't know what's wrong with my code:

[image]

I already checked about the index and really sure the index is real:

[image]

When I execute the function this error pops up:

[image]

I'd really appreciate any help and suggestions.

Comment: Looking into the traces in Laravel log file and find out which file and line does the error occurs.

Comment: You should include the code as text in the post instead of posting images of it. Please consider these guidelines: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: i'm sorry because include the code as images, i'm already fix the problem...have a nice day sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just want to confirm this error because my excel having more than one sheet so for everyone have this problem you can include this code thank you

```
public function sheets() : array
{
    return [
        new FirstSheetImport()
    ];
}
```